# Extract strings from shapefile attribute using GDAL and Python 3.X

Tags: string, gdal, shapefile, rasterize

I have a shapefile that consists of two fields/attributes, one being integers, the other being strings.

I can extract the integers into Python array by first using the function `gdal.RasterizeLayer()` to burn the shapefile into a .tiff image as the first band. Then, I use `my_raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()` to read the integers as an array.

However, I would like to extract the string values from the other field/attribute. I doing the exact same thing but I have already changed the attribute name in the `gdal.RasterizeLayer()` specification. However, calling `GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()` only gives me zeros.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to read strings from rasters?

Btw: I'm using the exact same code as [here](http://ceholden.github.io/open-geo-tutorial/python/chapter_4_vector.html).

Check it out from

> **Pure Python version -- gdal.RasterizeLayer**

Comment: My raster can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iq759fclrkfmyar/Area1_geo.tiff?dl=0

Comment: My shapefile can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/awt6zzc63rbxfwm/Sectors.shp?dl=0

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about why you need the rasterization part? Why would you need an "array of strings"? Its seems easier to just read the attributes of the shapefile. And if needed rasterize a mask for which you use the attributes as a lookup table.

Comment: Sure. I'm classifying crop land using different pixel-based machine learning algorithms. Having done so, I create a heat map of the crop probabilities, and from the heat map you can easily see the crop land. Next, I want to know which sectors/areas/districts these pixels belong to and for this, I want to use the shape file with strings, like "Area 1", "Area ", etc for all the pixels. Maybe there is a smarter way to do this?